# Updateprogress never stops or hides even after work is completed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

Below is the code i have on my aspx page.  I am trying to gray out page with a loading image using the asp:UpdateProgress control.  Everything works, except the asp:UpdateProgress control never completes, even when the work is completed and the page is updated??? I am using a master page. I have to be missing something simple that ends the process.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatepanel1" DynamicLayout="false" DisplayAfter="0">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="overlay">
            <div id="modalprogress">
                <div id="theprogress">
                    <img alt="" src="ajax-loader.gif" />
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" AllowedFileTypes="xml" 
            AutoStartUpload="true" MaxFileSize="30000" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" 
            OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" Mode="Auto"
            runat="server" ClearFileListAfterUpload="True" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnReadXml" Text="Button" runat="server" 
            OnClick="btnReadXml_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblmessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"> 
        </asp:Label>
        <br />
        <FTB:FreeTextBox ID="txtAddendum" ToolbarLayout="SelectAll, Cut, Copy, 
            Paste, Delete, Undo, Redo;|Bold,Italic,Underline,BulletedList"
            runat="server" Height="500px" Width="100%">
        </FTB:FreeTextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        filter: Alpha(Opacity=80);
        opacity: 0.80;
        -noz-opacity: 0.80;
    }

    #theprogress {
        background-color: #038890;
        width: 110px;
        height: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        -noz-opacity: 1;
    }

    #modalprogress {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -11px 0 0 -55px;
        color: white;
    }

    body > #modalprogress {
        position: fixed;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: tried all this code on another page within my site and it works, i have no idea what is holding it up on the current page, any ideas?

Comment: If Not Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
            End If

this is in my page_load and is messing up the whole thing, when i take it out all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a AjaxFileUpload control inside an update panel. AjaxFileUpload controls force full postbacks -- this is *unavoidable*. There is no async postback for this control, and no point in them being inside an update panel, as issues could arise...

What's probably happening is that the *postback* caused by the AjaxFileUpload control starts the UpdateProgress control, but because the postback is not asynchronous, it "never ends" (because it never began asynchronously, it was just a synchronous postback).